# http put did not send any response in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hey I have this app where I can update status, and I use http.put method, but it takes forever to response. I got this error

error

[image: 1]

And here is the code for http.put

```
Future<void> mapEventToState(
  Emitter<ReportStatusState> emit, ReportStatusEvent event) async {
emit(ReportStatusLoading());
ReportStatusPut statusPut = event.statusPutBody;
// ReportStatusModel model =
//     await apiAuthRepository.updateReportStatus(statusPut, event.id);
ReportStatusModel model = await updateReportStatus({'biaya': '0', 'status': 'SELESAI'}, event.id);
print(model);
if (!model.success) {
  emit(ReportStatusFailure(model.message));
}
print(model.code);
emit(ReportStatusSuccess());
}}

Future<ReportStatusModel> updateReportStatus(
 Map data, String id) async {
 final SharedPreferencesManager sharedPreferencesManager = 
 locator<SharedPreferencesManager>();
 String? token = 
  sharedPreferencesManager.getString(SharedPreferencesManager.keyAccessToken);
 try {
final response = await http.put(
    Uri.parse('https://api.komplekku.com/officer/api/report/v1/$id'),
    body: json.encode(data),
headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'});
return ReportStatusModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
} catch (e) {
throw Exception(e);
}
}
```

There is nothing wrong with the API, I already check using Postman and it worked perfectly fine, Anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: The error message says that your request timed out. So did you check if there are any typos in the URL or that the server might have been down? Or is your auth token invalid and the server does not respond to it? What does your successful postman request look like?